# Foldr to union lists

Tags: haskell

Consider the following `myUnion` function, that must begin as follows:

```
myUnion xs ys = foldr ....
```

What I am trying to do is use `foldr` to create a new list that contains all elements of `xs` and `ys` without any duplicates. I must do this by first copying over all elements of `xs` that are not in `ys`, and then all the `ys` elements that remain after this check.

I have been trying to solve this problem for quite a while now without any success. I would naturally, try to break down `xs` or `ys` to `x:rest` and `y:rest2` and use the prelude function `elem` to check if some element is in a list, however having to use `foldr` suggests that there may be an easier way to go about it and makes it difficult for me to think about a way to solve this problem given that it must begin with foldr.

I appreciate any suggestions about how to tackle this problem.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Start with this definition: `foldr (:)` and then try to make it filter out the elements that are present in `ys`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't understand how to implement this because xs and ys are passed as lists and are not split up to head/tail. I am having a hard time  matching every single element from list xs against list ys, considering how the function must start.

Comment: Your function will have the following form: `myUnion xs ys = foldr (\x rest -> ...) ys xs`.

Comment: Another take: first find out how to use `foldr` to filter `ys` so it does not contain any element that equals `x`. Then modify it so that scalar `x` becomes the list `xs`. Note: efficiency is not the point of this exercise, but if you can spot the inefficiency, good for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that having list used for set isn't good idea:

```
myUnion xs ys = Data.List.foldr Data.Set.insert Data.Set.empty (xs ++ ys)
```

If you have sorted lists of uniq value you probably want to use unfoldr:

```
myUnions xs0 ys0 = unfoldr walk (xs0, ys0) where
    walk ([], []) = Nothing
    walk ([], (y:ys')) = Just (y, ([], ys'))
    walk ((x:xs'), []) = Just (x, (xs', []))
    walk (xs@(x:xs'), ys@(y:ys')) | x < y = Just (x, (xs', ys))
                                  | x > y = Just (y, (xs, ys'))
                                  | otherwise = Just (x, (xs', ys'))
```

But if you still insist:

```
myUnion xs ys = foldr myInsert [] (xs++ys) where
    myInsert x zs = if x `elem` zs then zs else (x:zs)

-- this one expects that both lists have uniq items
-- and checks only elements from xs for presence in ys
myUnion xs ys = foldr myInsert ys xs where
    myInsert x zs = if x `elem` ys then zs else (x:zs)
-- but this should be written differently I guess
myUnion xs ys = filter (`notElem` ys) xs ++ ys
```

Comment: +1, Thanks for the reply. I have a question, doesn't `foldr` take 3 parameters? `foldr <func> <val> <list>`? I don't understand how foldr ends up not returning any error. Your helper function returns `zs` which is a list, if one condition is true, and `x:zs` which is also a list if another condition is true. Either way, wouldn't we end up with `foldr <list>` and insufficient number of arguments? I appreciate any clarification.

Comment: Yes `foldr` takes 3 arguments: function to transform last result with next element (`myInsert` or `Data.Set.insert`), first "result" to pass first time to combine function (`[]` or `Data.Set.empty`) and of course list of elements (`xs ++ ys`). But I can't understand how you've got "we end up with `foldr <list>`".

Comment: @AnchovyLegend, Consider `foldr f b [x0,x1,x2] = f x0 (f x1 (f x2 b))`. Possible implementation `{ myFoldr _ b [] = b; myFoldr f b (x:xs) = f x (myFoldr f b xs) }`

Comment: thanks for the reply. Sorry I don't understand your example, I am relatively new to Haskell. Do you mind breaking down the logic? I am under the impression that we ended up with foldr <list> because we are calling the helper function myInsert that takes two arguments and returns a list, so foldr arguments end up being a single list?

Comment: @AnchovyLegend, Agghhh.... Got it! :) You think that `foldr myInsert [] (xs ++ ys)` is evaluated as first `result = myInsert [] (xs ++ ys)` and then `foldr (result)`. No syntax is different `foldr` takes `myInsert` (function) as a first argument, then `[]` as a second argument and `(xs ++ ys)` as its third argument. In C-like languages that call might look like `foldr(myInsert, {}, listConcat(xs, ys))`. So it may be written like `foldr (myInsert) ([]) (xs ++ ys)`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. So in other words, `myInsert` takes in no parameters (i.e. void function?) This makes more sense as far as satisfying the `foldr` arguments however it does not make a lot of sense as far as how the list variables are passed  into variables `x` `zs`?

Comment: @AnchovyLegend, issue is in the way you read expression. `myInsert` is function that takes two parameters, but when that identifier (that refers to that function) passed as argument to `foldr` it doesn't fire right away with taking two parameters on the right side of it. It just passed as reference to some function which can be called later with two parameters passed. `foldr` takes it first parameter and then few times applies to it two arguments (first is element of list and second is last result or initial "result"). I guess you need read more about syntax of Haskell or similar languages